# Different list item

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation, html-lists

Hey, I've a very funny problem. I have a very loong ul li a menu and want to have ONE item with different width and height.

The menu looks like this:

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li id="smaller"><a href="#" id="smallerLink">The smallest item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Another item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Another item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Another item</a></li>
  (...)
</ul>
```

Then I have something like in:

style.css:

```
#nav {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  line-width: 2em;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

#nav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

#smaller {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}

#smallerLink {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

Why the first item isn't 10x10px?

Comment: Have you examined Firebug to see what the applied styles are? Have you tried adding the `!important` flag after the declarations.

Comment: I did. The "smaller" and "smallerlink" styles doesn't apply, but no idea why.

Comment: What *is* being applied to the first item? Can you post a live demo somewhere (http://jsbin.com/ or http://jsfiddle.net/ are personal (free) favourites)?

Answer (score 2):

Because it contains an a-tag with width and height of 20px. Set overflow:hidden on your #smaller css definition, then it should work. **And make it #nav li#smaller for greater specifity.**

```
#nav li#smaller {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    overflow: hidden
}
```

Comment: If you change `#smaller` to `#nav li#smaller` like I wrote in my answer, then it should work.